# Movie or TV series' episode where a bad guy was punished by putting him in a deadly maze

Tags: episode-identification, story-identification

The maze was constructed using wood, I think. Also there were dogs inside with him, and razor blades stuck to the walls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be [Tales from the Crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Crypt_%28film%29), the movie.

This excerpt from Wikipedia is relevant (emphasis is mine)

> **Blind Alleys** (Tales from the Crypt #46, February–March 1955), Major
>   William Rogers (Nigel Patrick), the new director of a home for the
>   blind (making up mostly of elderly and middle-aged men), makes drastic
>   financial cuts, reducing heat and rationing food for the residents,
>   while he lives in luxury with Shane, his Belgian Malinois. When he
>   ignores complaints and a man dies due to the cold, the blind
>   residents, led by the stone-faced George Carter (Patrick Magee) exact
>   an equally cruel revenge. After Carter and his group subdue the staff,
>   they lure and trap Major Rogers as well as his dog in two separate
>   rooms in the basement. The blind men then begin constructing in the
>   basement a **maze of narrow corridors, some of them lined with razor
>   blades. They starve the Major's dog, then place the Major in the
>   maze's center, release the dog and turn off the basement lights**...