# Blind people take revenge against evil asylum manager

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched the "Tales from the Crypt" movie, and the story of the blind people taking revenge on the evil asylum administrator was shockingly familiar. I tried to some other similar movie, and I only found [**this answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28539/122822).

Additionally, I was quite sure it must have been some episode from "Twilight zone" (I watched it some time ago, but [**this page**](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_(1959_TV_series)) failed my expectations.

So what other movie has the same story?

Comment: This 2008 movie has a very similar plot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness_(2008_film)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that I was thinking of another "Tales from the Crypt" work. Specifically, Episode 5 of season 6 of the "Tales from the Crypt" series titled [**"Revenge is the Nuts"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tales_from_the_Crypt_episodes#Season_6_(1994%E2%80%9395)) tells the same story, slightly altered.

> Arnie Grunwald (Anthony Zerbe) is the sadistic and psychopathic head caretaker at a home for the blind. He routinely goes out of his way to abuse the home's patients, Samuel, Armelia, and Osgood (Issac Hayes, Bibi Besch, and Tim Sampson), by lining the walls with razor blades, walling off the bathrooms, spilling marbles on the floor, and unleashing his guard dog Bruno on them. When Shelia (Teri Polo), a new patient, arrives at the home, Arnie agrees to tone down the borderline inhumane conditions at the home if she sleeps with him. Refusing to do so, Shelia teams up with the other patients and Arnie's abused brother Benny (John Savage) to ensure that Arnie gets his much deserved comeuppance.

Comment: That page notes "This episode's plot is adapted from Blind Alleys which was told in Tales From The Crypt #46 while using the title of the Vault of Horror story listed above."